# Can you set ReferenceLoopHandling to ignore with NEST elasticsearch client?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am integrating ElasticSearch into one of our websites. When migrating products I am getting this error alot.

```
self referencing loop detected for type 'mytype'
```

I have read about it, and you can set the property ReferenceLoopHandling of the JsonSerializerSettings to ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore. Is there any way to do that with NEST?

//Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nest opens the serializersettings it uses up using

```
client.ModifyJsonSerializationSettings(s=> {
    //do with JsonSerializerSettings s here what you want
});
```

This allows you to also register custom converters and the like.